# Best way to use the TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

My application is crashing sporadically and it's because I'm making a call to `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` a little too quickly after the application has loaded.

From a little testing, I've fixed the issue using a readonly `TaskScheduler` field and populating it in the class's constructor (thanks to another SO answer) but am worried this single instance of a `TaskScheduler` will have negative consequences due to the size of the application and the dependency on the `TaskScheduler`.

Has anyone **A)** made the change from calling `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to instantiating a single instance in the constructor and **B)** had success with it?

Comment: How about showing us some sample code to be more clear on what you mean?  What class' constructor are you talking about? What type of application are we talking about?